# Running Eclipse on Windows 7 JRE and JDK not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I downloaded the latest Eclipse on Windows 7. When I click the eclipse icon it throws the following exception:

[image]

I have already installed JRE and JDK.

UPDATE: Eclipse.ini contents:

```
   -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the Eclipse documentation, you *may* need to specify the VM **before** the VM args, and the path should not be on the same line as the -vm switch:

> - The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
> - The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
> - The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.

[Source: Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

For example:

```sh
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

You also might need to surround your path with some quotes, since it contains spaces.  I **always** install things like Eclipse and Java in root directories with no spaces, not under `Program Files`, to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thx I used this example and it worked:
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Answer (score 1):

Reference the location of your **JRE** path in the eclipse configuration file, `eclipse.ini`.

Note that you only need a **JRE** to launch Eclipse, but once Eclipse is launched, you should register a **JDK** for your projects. This is done via

```
Preferences-> Java -> Installed JREs
```

Comment: Eclipe.ini is pasted in the original question.

Comment: I dont know where to add the path. Should the path point to the bin folder of the JRE

Comment: -vm
C:\yourLocation\jrex.x.x\bin

Comment: I have updated the original question with the latest eclipse.ini contents. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me on win7. I had 2 folders for 'program files'

1. Program files
2. Program Files(x86)

java folder was present on both. For environment variables, I have given the path of java from program files(x86)...\jre6\bin. Then I had downloaded new java 7 version update. Then had tried to open eclipse, it worked and i had not made any changes to eclipse.ini file. My eclipse.ini didnt have any reference to the -vm argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same of problem because I was have both the java 1.7 and the java 1.8 and I solved the problem By :

for windows :

**first :**

open your **CMD** and write **java -version** 
the result is the current version of java on your pc for exampe the result is 1.8 so

**second**

open the **eclipse.ini** and if the path was not the path of current version java (that shown in result of CMD) edit  the path to correct path of your java (the version shown in result )
like this :

**before** I change the path was :

-vm

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe**

-vmargs

**-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7**

-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

**after** I check of my version of java using CMD the result is : java 1.8
so I change the path and version like this :

-vm

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe**

-vmargs

**-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8**

-Xms256m

-Xmx1024m

Nice Day :)