# JRE and JDK intalled but Eclipse doesn't starts

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have installed JDK and JRE.

I just downloaded **ADT PLUGIN x64 and x86** in my **Win 8 pro x64**.

But when I start Eclipse, it still says "A JDK or JRE is necessary to run Eclipse....not found in your PATH..."

I added the PATH to bin directory of JDK too but It did not work.

Comment: check the eclipse.ini and add the `-vm <<jdk full path>>` direction.

Comment: see if this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717119/running-eclipse-on-windows-7-jre-and-jdk-not-found

Comment: @user2511414 did so, it says failed to load JNI library "<<jdk path>> jvm.dll"

Comment: @UmairAyub reinstall the JDK

Comment: can you take a screenshot and post ??

Comment: I reinstalled but it di not come of. I have jdk7 u15. Should download the latest one?

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Dear, I have posted all the messages that it shows.

Comment: @user2511414 is it the case of 63 or 32 bit? I have win 8 pro 64 bit

Comment: no difference, but it's recommended download the JDK1.7.0.40 X64

Comment: @user2511414 I have googled now and some have answered that their problem solved after installing jdk 64-bit. I am now dowloading jdk-64-bit, let see if it works.

Comment: @UmairAyub could you fix the problem?! I'm happy if I could give some hand.

Answer (score 0):

possibly can have your jdk and jre duplicates. For safety uninstall completely and install again. As a recommendation works with the JDK and JRE for x86.

When you have them installed correctly added in the Windows environment variables JAVA_HOME the direction of JDK folder.

for example

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Eclipse does not know where to find your JDK.

The easiest solution is to go into your Eclipse installation folder and edit the eclipse.ini file so that the top line contains

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe
```

or wherever your JDK is located within your system.