# Android Eclipse Exit Code=15

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I accidentally closed eclipse **when I was sending my application to run on my phone**, and when I went to open it I got the following error:

```
Java was started but returned exit code= 15
C:\windows\system32\javaw.exe
Dogsi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

I have **tried restarting** my computer but it didn't change this message. I have been using eclipse for a while, and have never seen this error before.

How can I resolve this error?

EDIT:

I ended up just reinstalling eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Eclipse Exit Code Fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824502/android-eclipse-exit-code-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like eclipse didn't get a chance to save its configuration properly while quitting, and now the configuration is invalid when attempting to open.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059686/jdk-error-while-running-eclipse-on-windows-7 and [Running Eclipse on Windows 7 JRE and JDK not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717119/running-eclipse-on-windows-7-jre-and-jdk-not-found/16805632#16805632) . Alternatively, just reinstall the jre and ecipse, but if you don't want to do that, then you're going to have to fiddle with eclipse configuration.

Comment: thank you for the answer! How could I edit the eclipse config. to work