# eclipse not opening, gives error saying no java virtual machine found

Tags: eclipse

I recently upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 8.1 pro. But when I try to open up eclipse, i get an error saying. "Java development Kit (JDK) must be available to run eclipse, no Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations.
C:\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your Current PATH"
Any help would be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Eclipse on Windows 7 JRE and JDK not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717119/running-eclipse-on-windows-7-jre-and-jdk-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is simply an IDE. It requires some instance of Java to be able to run properly. Go to
[this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and download the JDK and install it. Then it should work!

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html