# java EE can not see javaw.exe in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I install JDK and JRE in window But when I run Eclipse.exe then that error show to me even the javaw.exe existing in the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin
, I search on Google someone say to put the javaw.exe in the folder of Eclipse But that not working for me,

This picture show the javaw.exe existing in the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin and show the error of Eclipse

[image: this picture show the javaw.exe existing in the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin and show the error of eclipse]

so any help?

**Update:**

See comments why this is **not a duplicate** of [*Running Eclipse on Windows 7 JRE and JDK not found*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16717119/6505250)

Comment: Where did you specify the path to java? In the system settings? Or in the eclipse.ini? Did you set the pathname exclusively the name of the .exe file as pathname?

Comment: Does `eclipse.ini` contain the line `-vm`? On the command line, what is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: @howlger on command line java version "1.8.0_45" But in eclipse.ini C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: @howlger I change the path to java version 1.8 , because it the version of my pc , and it work than you very much

Comment: @rkosegi  I did not found the answer in duplicate question the howlger help me to solve it , plz stop make my question as dublicate to post my answer for help people :)

Comment: @ Henry I did not found the answer in duplicate question the howlger help me to solve it , plz stop make my question as dublicate to post my answer for help people :)

Comment: NO problem I post my answer on duplicate question , so people can try my solution :)